# reading of the counter 種

Tags: readings, counters, terminology

How does one read the counter 種 in this dictionary entry?

[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/三毒/#jn-91663](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%89%E6%AF%92/#jn-91663)

仏語【ぶつご】。人【ひと】の善心【ぜんしん】を害【がい】する3種の煩悩【ぼんのう】。貪【とん】・瞋【しん】・痴【ち】。

*There are three kinds of vexations harmful to human virtue: greed, anger, and ignorance.*

According to the entry for 種 in Jim Breen's wwwjdic, two readings seem possible for "varieties":

種【くさ】 ; (n,n-suf) (2) variety; kind; (n,ctr) (3) counter for varieties

種【しゅ】 ; (n,n-suf) (1) kind; variety; (n,n-suf)

Comment: I’m not an expert, but the normal reading is 〜しゅ. I haven’t encountered the reading くさ before myself, but it seems like it’s an old reading that isn’t used much anymore. At least I think that’s the case.

Comment: (Also note that, when the reading 〜くさ is actually used, it should be counted ひとくさ、ふたくさ、みくさ… )

Comment: [三種{みくさ} in a dictionary.](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%BF%E3%81%8F%E3%81%95/)

Comment: From my experience, 貪・瞋・痴 is pronounced とんじんち instead of とんしんち when grouped together as 三毒 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern Japanese, 種 as a counter for kinds/species is always read **しゅ**. 3種 is さんしゅ.

くさ is an archaic counter that is no longer in use. You don't have to remember it unless you are studying archaic Japanese literature seriously.